# how to parse the data from Json String using volley?

Tags: android, json, listview

[image]

In the first activity we will show only the date  of the purchased and total quantity in a List View. And when user will click on a List Item we will show the  items and quantity details in the next activity.

[after clicking on date user will go to next activity where it will show  the product name n quantity ]

here is the code for  what i have tried

```
    private ArrayList<parse> milkParss;


    //for Adapter
    private DateAdapter adapter ;
     //Initializing  the listview
        listView_1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_1);
        //to get the data from method getData
        adapter = new DateAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_list,);

        listView_1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView_1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MonthlySummaryActivity.this, UpdateDailySupply.class);
                intent2.putExtra(KEY_DATE, );
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });


        //initializing the milkpar
        milkPar = new ArrayList<parse>();

               private void sendRequest() {

        //for processing dialog box

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //  JSONArrayRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlJsonArray, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlJsonArray, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                try {
                    //parsing the value of jsaon array
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                        String da = person.getString("date");
                        String pr = person.getString("product");
                        String na = person.getString("Person");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MonthlySummaryActivity.this, "ERROR" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                },
                   new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MonthlySummaryActivity.this, "error::" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
}





public class DateAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<parse> list = new ArrayList<parse>();
    private Context context ;

    public DateAdapter(List<parse> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = convertView ;
        if (view == null ){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list,null);

        }
        return convertView ;
    }
}
```

[image: [2]]

Comment: Post your code which you have tried.

Comment: volley is for making http requests. for networking. for parsing data you have nothing to do with volley

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some code and a question, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: can u give me the suggestion

Comment: @cricket_007 here is the code what i have tried please  suggest me

Comment: @Masum here is the code

Answer (score 0):

Getting used to android's volley may be confusing at first, but once you get the hang of it, it will be easy. Once you have the data from parsing JSON, you can then pass it to another activity using bundle or extra from `Intent`.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, myUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //getting the response
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String name;
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            name= jsonObject.getString("name");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.wtf("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    }) {
//sending a request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", id);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
```